# 500 internal server error phpmyadmin and other webapps after update PHP version from 5.3 to 5.4 on direct admin

Tags: apache, nginx, directadmin

I updated my directadmin server's php version from 5.3 to 5.4 for installing last version of ioncube loader.
After upgrading, I found a 500 error on webapps like phpMyAdmin, roundcube ect.
I have tried many solutions such as:

- Rebuild apache
- Checking permissions and ownership of the /var/www folder and subfolders
- Checking alias settings at the httpd.conf file and httpd-alias.conf

But my problem still exists.
Now, when I create a html file on the /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin folder like test.html and then open myserverip/phpmyadmin/test.html, it runs. But it doesn't work with php file(test.php or phpMyAdmin's index.php) and I receive 500 error.

My server's specification:
OS: CentOS 6.0
Webserver: nginx_apache
Control Panel: Directadmin
PHP version: 5.4
Apache version: 2.x

This is my error log file after cleaning and running this action:
[Thu Oct 01 13:12:54.315024 2015] [:error] [pid 17550:tid 2582453104] [client 84.241.32.113:21899] PHP Warning:  Module 'ionCube Loader' already loaded in Unknown on l$
[Thu Oct 01 13:12:54.315196 2015] [:error] [pid 17550:tid 2582453104] [client 84.241.32.113:21899] [Thu Oct 01 13:12:54 2015] [warn-phpd] The ionCube PHP Loader is dis$
[Thu Oct 01 13:12:54.316188 2015] [core:error] [pid 17550:tid 2582453104] [client 84.241.32.113:21899] End of script output before headers: index.php

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Better ask on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I can see there is an issues with the ionCube PHP Loader. Can you please try to reinstall that on your server and check this again.